# Add Related data to Identity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

There are loads of EF code-first tutorials using `IdentityUser` interface, but none of is getting to the point of how to add/update related data to the user. I'm using ASP.NET MVC, so let's say I have the following user model

```
  public class AppUser : IdentityUser
  {
      public ICollection<Message> msges { get; set; }
  }
```

And the a model for the messages

```
public class Message
{
    public string MessageId { get; set; }

    public string msg { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime msgTime { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
}
```

And of course the `dbcontext` class creating the message table and building up the one-to-many relationship between the 2 models.

```
public class AppIdentityDBContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
    public AppIdentityDBContext() : base() 
    { }

    public AppIdentityDBContext(DbContextOptions<AppIdentityDBContext> options) : base(options) 
    { }

    public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<AppUser>()
                .HasMany(x => x.msges)
                .WithOne(y => y.AppUser);
    }
}
```

This is all cool, but how am I going to add a new message entry for the appropriate user? Reading tutorials with "similar" problems, I read that the `UserManager` instances job is to update the user data. So I tried something like this in the controller:

```
 // Find the user, what works
 AppUser Benny = UserMan.FindAsyncByName("BennyHill");

 // I create a message object than I add it the Benny's msgs property
 Benny.msgs.Add(newMessage);   // --> for some reason this throws nullreference exception

 // Next step would be to update the data with the UserManager instance
 await UserMan.UpdateAsync(Benny);
```

Any wisdom is welcomed. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error will be due to the collection in the entity being defaulted to #null.
To add to the collection you should eager-load the collection first. Firstly it can be helpful to set up the collection as virtual so that EF proxies it and can lazy load if necessary. It helps to initialize collection members automatically to avoid null refs especially when 'new'ing up an entity...

```
public class AppUser:IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Message> msges { get; set; } = new List<Message>();
}
```

From here your example will probably work, as you can add new items to the msges collection, though typically when working with the collections you will want to eager-load the list:

if `UserMan.FindAsyncByName` returns `IQueryable<AppUser>` then:

```
AppUser Benny= await UserMan.FindAsyncByName("BennyHill").Include(x => x.Msges);
```

Otherwise, inside `FindAsyncByName` you'll want to include the `.Include(x => x.Msges)`

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the help. I think the Include is what I tried to figure out. The problem now is that Include does not work asynchronously, and the usermanager has no synchronous methods(funny circle). It feels like, IdentityUser inherited entities can be customized, but you can't get too far with it.

Comment: I ended up with the following line:  AppUser Benny = await UserMan.Users.Include(x => x.msges).SingleAsync(x => x.UserName == user); It seems to be working, the starting point was the Include method, thanks.